# Jelastic Service Management App: Can't select my provider in iOS App for iPad

Tags: ipad, jelastic

While i am successfully using the iPhone Jelastic App to start/stop my web application or check my billing details, I cannot connect to my specific provider (Dogado a german provider) with the iPad version of the App.

I am using an iPad Pro 9.7inch with iOS 9.3.2. The App version is 2.1.

The login page of the puplic cloud service proposes a provider in Luxembourg, but pressing the down arrow does not open the list of providers, making it impossible to choose my provider.

Eventually I cannot log-in and the iPad App useless.

I would love to have a fix for this login interface and would love to use the App on my iPad.

Best regards.

Comment: Did you contact @Jelastic or Dogado directly about this? I don't think there's anything someone can do to fix or workaround this particular issue on SO...

Comment: Well, I went to the AppStore and followed the link 'Support' provided there. That link led me right here on StackExchange. After searching for a similar question I decided to add mine. Thanks for the advice. You mention @jelastic which makes me think you're suggesting to use Twitter to contact them. Is that really the best way to contact them?

Comment: Ok. Guess the developers will spot this thread eventually and offer some kind of assistance. Still, you might want to mention it to Dogado to speed things up :-)

Comment: Just posted on their web site. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

It caused because of a bug. It will be fixed in the next version of Jelastic iOS application. We're sorry for delayed answer.